# Prove that if $X\cap Y=\emptyset$, then $X\cup Y$ has $n+m$ elements.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $X$ and $Y$ be sets with $n$ and $m$ elements, respectively. Prove that if $X\cap Y=\emptyset$, then $X\cup Y$ has $n+m$ elements.

It's clear to me intuitively how this is true. I understand that if two sets have no elements in common, then there is no 'repetition' in the union and the number of elements of the union is the sum of the number of elements in each set. How could I formalize this? Is there a way to do it by induction? I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
\begin{align}
|X\cup Y| =|X|+|Y|-|X\cap Y|
\end{align}

Edit: Suppose $X$ is a fixed set with $m$ elements.

Base case: $Y$ be a set with one element and $X\cap Y = \emptyset$. Then it follows immediately that $|X\cup Y|= m+1$.

Inductive case: the proposition holds when $k=n$, i.e. if $|Y|=n$ and $X\cap Y =\emptyset$ then $|X\cup Y| = m+n$. Next, consider the case $k=n+1$, i.e. let $Y=\{y_1\}\cup Y_1$ where $|Y_1|=n$ and $X\cap Y=\emptyset$. Then if follows
\begin{align}
|X\cup Y| = |X\cup Y_1\cup\{y_1\}|= |X\cup Y_1|+1 =m+n+1.
\end{align}

Comment: I guess his question is how you actually prove this rigorously.

Comment: @jacky chong I can't use this

Comment: @KelKel23 what are you allow to use?

Comment: @JackyChong Not entirely sure. This is part of a section where we are learning about proofs by induction and minimal counter example

Comment: @amWhy: You're right, I shouldn't make such assumptions (should have written 'the question' in stead).

Comment: @Mathematician42  I appreciate your comment.  I've delete my comment immediately above your last comment.

Comment: @amWhy: You are right to point this out, I hoped I haven't offended the OP in case I was wrong. I try to be aware of latent sexism but clearly mess-ups still happen. Maybe if more people call this behaviour out, it will be easier to unlearn it. So again, I believe you are right to call it out and I do not mind other people reading this, on the contrary, it might make them reflect about it as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can write $X=\left\{x_1, \dots , x_n\right\}$ and $Y=\left\{y_1, \dots , y_m\right\}$. Since $|X|=n$, we have that $x_i=x_j\Leftrightarrow i=j$ and similarly for $Y$. By definition $X\cup Y=\left\{x_1, \dots , x_n, y_1, \dots ,y_n\right\}$. Clearly $|X\cup Y|\leq n+m$. Now suppose  $|X\cup Y|< n+m$ then at least two elements of $X\cup Y$ must be equal. Since the $x_i$ are all different and the $y_j$ are also all different, the only possibility is that $x_i=y_j$ for some $i$ and $j$. But then $x_i\in X\cap Y$ contrary to the assumption.

This proof requires very little. You can also prove the formula suggested by the other answers using induction, but it might be a bit tricky to formulate the induction hypothesis precisely.